# android - callback function - Dialog now showing

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have a class XMPPClient which implements the Player interface, which is used to callback certain function. I'm calling the interface's callback functions from XMPPManager into XMPPClient, where the functions are located.

In XMPPClient I have the following interface callback function:

```
 public void request_play(String player) {
    Dialog request_dialog2 = new Dialog(this);
    request_dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_request2);
    request_dialog2.setTitle(R.string.response_title);
    TextView dialog_message = (TextView)request_dialog2.findViewById(R.id.response_message);
    dialog_message.append(player);
    request_dialog2.setCancelable(true);

    Button button1 = (Button)request_dialog2.findViewById(R.id.response_accept);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button2 = (Button)request_dialog2.findViewById(R.id.response_decline);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    });
    request_dialog2.show();
  }
```

In XMPPManager I'm using the following code to actually call the callback function:

```
      PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
      connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

              if(body.equals("play")) {
                player_avail.request_play("test");
              }
            }
       }
```

Where connection is of type: XMPPConnection.

I'm calling XMPPClient normally with:

Intent intent_remote = new Intent(this, XMPPClient.class);
  startActivity(intent_remote);

The problem is that the Dialog request_dialog2 (in request_play()) isn't being shown on the screen. If I create an Activity instead of Dialog, the Activity is run just fine, but not the Dialog.

What can be the cause of that?

Also, the XMPPManager is not being run in a separate thread, since currently I'm not far in the development process and it's the thing I have to add.

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could it be probably due to the layout? you can find more information on example code on creating the dialog [1](http://www.androidadb.com/source/platform/frameworks/base/tests/ImfTest/src/com/android/imftest/samples/DialogActivity.java.html) and [2](http://www.androidadb.com/source/platform/frameworks/base/tests/ImfTest/src/com/android/imftest/samples/EditTextActivityDialog.java).

Comment: Hi. I used a dialog from the example you posted and created a dialog like this: 
Intent intent_start = new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class);
startActivity(intent_start);

But that didn't help. Still no dialog. The XMPPClient's layout consists of ListActivity. Maybe that's the cause for strange behaviour?

Comment: hello, why don't you try it and see? Probably debugging by printing the line, yes tedious but when you are not knowing where is the problem, this way of debugging can be a *start* to locate the cause of error or better understand what is happening and then get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a callback, for example to get the dialog data, inside the onResume() methods of your dialog.
The onResume() will be called after the dialog is showed.
I do this, inside the dialog, if I need a callback to request data for the dialog to the activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(hasData() && mCallback != null){  // Check if already has data
        mCallback.getDialogData();
    }
}
```

have a nice day and a nice coding :D